# Have formula treat value as text, not numeric

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I have an Excel formula reading data from a column. The data in that column is sometimes a date-like format, such as "10-11". Despite the fact that I've ensured that column is text formatted -- and all values display correctly as plain text, not reinterpreted as dates -- the formula is basically reinterpreting them as dates in the reference.

I need a way to force the formula's cell reference to interpret the cell as text. I tried TEXT(A1, "@") but it doesn't work -- it gives the numeric value of the date.

Comment: You probably need to show us what formula you are having the problem with, there may be a workaround based on that specific formula.

Comment: here is the formula, which retrieves the first set of numeric values from the cell data -- stopping at alpha or symbol characters: =LEFT(A1,LEN(LOOKUP(9.9E+307,MID(A1,1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))))+0)))

Comment: So your example should return "10" then?

Comment: Yes. But per comment below -- the data could be "147-23" -> return 147, or "76A" -> return 76

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brian Camire's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898958/excel-force-cell-format-in-formula/6901694#6901694) explains why, but here's a worksheet function that will work for you.  Note that you have to create that numeric array in it based on how long the longest string will be.  It's an array formula, so when you first enter it you have to hit CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER, then you can click and drag it down the column.

```
=LEFT(A1, MATCH(FALSE, ISNUMBER(VALUE(MID(A1, {1,2,3,4,5}, 1))),0) - 1)
```

Comment: that worked beautifully -- thanks! i'll need to read up on array formulas. i'm not familiar with them.

Comment: @Brian, I avoid array formulas whenever I can, but they can be critical some times. They basically let you use arrays (ranges) of values as parameters, and loop through all the values.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:  When referring to number-like (or date-like) text values in a formula, don't use them in a place in the formula where Excel is expecting a number.

Long answer:  Even if the source column is formatted as text *and* the values in the source column are truly entered as text (and not numbers, including dates), Excel may automatically convert text values to numbers (including dates) when you reference them in a formula *if* you use them in a place where Excel is expecting a number (or date).

For example (assuming US date formats), in a blank worksheet:

1. Set the format for column A to Text.
2. In cell A1, enter the value 10-11.
3. In cell B1, enter the formula =T(A1).  The T() worksheet function returns the supplied value if it is text.  Otherwise, it returns an empty string.  The result of the formula in cell B1 should be 10-11, indicating that the value of A1 is text, not a number or date (in which case the result would be an empty string).
4. In cell C1, enter the formula =A1.
5. In cell D1, enter the formula =T(C1).  The result should also be 10-11, indicating that the value of the formula in C1 is text, not a number or date.  This shows that you can (sometimes) use a text value that looks like a number (or date) in a formula and have Excel treat it as text (which is what you want).
6. In cell E1, enter the formula =A1+0.  The result will be 40827.  This is the numeric value of the date October 11, 2011.  This shows that you can (sometimes) use a text value that looks like a number (or date) in a formula and Excel will automatically convert it to a number (which is what you observed) if you use it in a place (like on either side of the + operator) where Excel is expecting a number.

Answer (score 5):

To insert a value into a cell and have it not be auto-formatted, and just treated as text, you can enter it like this:

```
=("cell data")
```

eg:

```
=("+1 3456789")
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use **`&""`**, Excel **converts the results of a formula to text** (like `*1` would convert to numbers).

Thus, you can use this formula:

```
=TEXT(A1;"jj-mm")&""
```

Comment: this didn't work. it partially worked for the specific data, but the result was: "jj-10". the bigger issue is that it breaks other data. the data in this cell includes formats such as: "10-11" "104-2" "134-45" "45B" "6413-A". my need is pretty simple -- the formula I use works fine, so long as the data is interpreted as simple text. but Excel is annoyingly treating the 2 digit - dash - 2 digit data as a date, which breaks the formula.

Answer (score 1):

If you put a single quote in front of the text in the cell, it should be represented as text on all references:

```
'10-11
```

Comment: this didn't work. the formula is still interpreting the cell as a date converted to a number.

Comment: but now there is a single quote in your cell data, how to get this to work without having the quote appear in your data?

Comment: On my version of Excel (mac:2011) it works fine, and there isn't any quote in the data.You can also try: `="10-11"`

Answer (score 0):

Just add zero to the input!

I was having a similar problem where I had a list of numbers with a text prefix (like FOO-1, FOO-25, FOO-979) but I just wanted the number part (1, 25, 979) so I could run another formula off of that. I was using SUBSTITUTE to replace the text portion with blank, but my other formula using these numbers was coming up with bogus results. I ended up making my formula like this:

=SUBSTITUTE(B1:B10,"FOO-","")+0, and now the ISNUMBER is saying TRUE where before it was saying FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a form worksheet that is used by dealers to ad parts and have it calculate the final cost; it references a locked "products" sheet. The problem is that I had no way of controlling what they entered.

```
Products can be like:
101 = A true number
7-2009 = Reads as date
7-5601-RT = TEXT/NUMBER reads as both number or text (NOT SOLVED YET)
CP6072CD = reads as plain text
```

I have most of this figured out; the only one that isn't is the one that reads as both text/Number.

In case anyone is looking for a similar solution, i did the following:
I created three additional columns to test and display the three different cases: "NUMBER", "DATE" , "TEXT".

```
DATE:         =NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(B42)))
ISOTHER:      =(ISNUMBER(--(MID(B42,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B42))),1))))
NUMBER:       =ISNUMBER(B42)
NUMBER/TEXT:  =NOT SOLVED YET

I42 = DATE
J42 = NUMBER
K42 = OTHER
L42 = TEXT
M42 = THE RESULT OF THE QUERY BELOW

=IF(AND(I42 = FALSE, J42 = FALSE, K42 = TRUE), "NUMBER", IF(AND( I42 = TRUE, J42= FALSE, K42=TRUE), "DATE", "TEXT"))
```

This (ABOVE) tests all the true/false results and depending on what the value turns out to be, I format each of them using:

```
ISNUMBER = VALUE(B42)
DATE FORMATTED AS B42*1
ELSE TEXT - AS ORIGINAL

=IF(M42 = "NUMBER", VALUE(B42), IF(M42 = "DATE", B42*1, B42))
```

So now I just need to figure out how to test if something is both text and number because the 7-5601-RT tests out as the same as number: "FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE"